# Build Failing with React Firebase Hooks and Vite

Tags: reactjs, firebase, build, vite

I am trying to build my react project with vite and it is throwing the following error.

```
node_modules/react-firebase-hooks/auth/dist/auth/types.d.ts:2:50 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'AuthActionHook'.
 
2 export declare type EmailAndPasswordActionHook = AuthActionHook<firebase.auth.UserCredential, firebase.FirebaseError>;
```

The dev version was working fine so I'm not sure what about the build is causing it to fail.

vite.config.js

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import reactRefresh from '@vitejs/plugin-react-refresh'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [reactRefresh()]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be caused by `react-firebase-hooks` module has error of type declaration. You can workaround by remove tsc command of build script in `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
  // "build": "tsc && vite build"
  "build": "vite build",
},
```

---

Alse, you can `skipLibCheck`:

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
}
```